# How can I find the length of a UTF8String in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am trying to calculate the length of the parameter input which I have converted into UTF8String.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try .count

```
let text = "test"
let utf8String = text.utf8
let utf8Length = utf8String.count
print(utf8Length);
```